# Parenting Bone Rig to model poses everything

Tags: rigging

So I am trying to rig this character model but when I go to move anything around after parenting, it just starts to move around everything. It didn't do this for my other model, that one worked fine.

https://youtu.be/gcORQmAW2Vw

Comment: That is an example of improper weight paint.  The leg is moving because the weight painting for the arm has included vertices from the leg.  You need to go to weight paint, select the vertex group for the arm bone you're moving, and delete all of the leg vertices that shouldn't be part of it.  If that failed, probably others did to.

Comment: @MartyFouts The whole model is blue, which I'm guessing it shouldn't be like that. Nothing is red so nothing is tied to anything I'm guessing. Should I start mapping?

Comment: How did you parent the rig to the model in the first place?  You might be able to fix it by undoing the parenting, cleaning up the model and trying again.

Comment: @MartyFouts I had 4 different sections of the model. the head, the arms, the upper body, and the lower body. I merged the 4 and then like the video shows, I parented the rig to the merged model. but now the parented rig won't pose the model anymore after adding an armature modifier to the body.

Answer (score 5):

In the video you parent the mesh to the armature deform using Envelope weights. That's a very different method from weight paint.

Basically, each bone has an "envelope" around it, and the target meshes will be affected depending on the envelopes they intersect with.

It's frankly not the most flexible method for skinning, and quite finicky to get right. So I'd recommend you to just stick to parent using automatic weight groups instead, and edit these weight groups in Edit mode or Weight paint.

- [Armature Deform Parent — Blender
  Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/armatures/skinning/parenting.html#with-envelope-weights)
- [Deform — Blender
  Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/armatures/bones/properties/deform.html#armature-bones-envelope)

Comment: Thanks I'll see if this changes anything and report back tomorrow!